# Field based off of a Cell value

Tags: excel, vba

What I need is a variable field for an Autofilter in VBA

So I'm currently building a data based including several businesses and trainings that they are required.  I am trying to create a macro that will go based of a specific cell to figure out which column to sort and then copy the range once sorted.  I was initially going to do a button for every business but this would consist of over 60 buttons as there are 60 rows.  Below is the code for one single business, what I would need is the auto filter field to be based on the cell range B85

```
Sub SMBstj()
'
' SMBstj Macro
'

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Training Data").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$CF$116").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("A3:G3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Report").Select
Range("C85").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,   SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Training Data").Select
Range("I2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$CF$116").AutoFilter Field:=8
Sheets("Report").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Criteria1:= Cells(85,2).Value` this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to look for a field value in the second row, you would need to use the following code:

```
Dim strField As String

With Sheets("Training Data")
    strField = Application.Match(.Range("B85").Value, .Range("2:2"), 0)
    .Range("$A$2:$CF$116").AutoFilter Field:=strField, Criteria1:="<>"
End With
```

Exemplary output:

[image]

**Edit:**

If cell B85 is in another sheet, you need to update the code as follows:

`Match(Sheets("Other Sheet").Range("B85").Value ...`

To be tested:

```
Dim varField            As Variant

With Sheets("Training Data")
    varField = Application.Match(Sheets("Other Sheet").Range("B85").Value, .Range("2:2"), 0)
    If IsNumeric(varField) Then
        Call .Range("$A$2:$CF$116").AutoFilter(Field:=varField, Criteria1:="<>")
    Else
        Call MsgBox(Prompt:=Sheets("Other Sheet").Range("B85").Value & " not found!", Buttons:=vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, Title:="Error")
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Won't that still be looking through Field  8 though ?

Comment: I would really need it to figure out Which field to look in based on cell B85 , so lets say if I have "Sol85" in cell B85 I need to autofilter from field 33 , but if "Sol84" is in cell B85 I need it to autofilter from Field 32.

Comment: Uhh sorry, my fault - I just realised you asked for `I am trying to create a macro that will go based of a specific cell to figure out which column to sort`. Let me edit my original post.

Comment: It's giving me a "Runtime error 9" Subscript out of range. I wonder if it's because the data is in a different worksheet than the Cell I need it to base the search on.

Comment: That's a correct guess! I'm updating my answer now to include another sheet.

Comment: I appreciate your help immensely.  I am still getting the same error once I get to this line : strField = Application.Match(Sheets("Report").Range("B85").Value, .Range("2:2"))

Comment: @kwen can you try again with the modified code (it's at the bottom of my post); let me know what the pop-up message shows you.

Comment: No problem at all! Feel free to up-vote/mark my answer as correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers